# What is the limit of $ln(ln(ln(...)))$ for successive compositions of $ln$ with itself?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If we do successive compositions of the natural log with itself and carry this to infinity, does it converge to zero?

Comment: As an example, taking $x_0 = 5$ we get $\ln(\ln(\ln(5)))=-0.7425....$, so the next $\ln$ is undefined.

Comment: MathJax hint:  if you put a backslash before common functions, you get the right font and spacing.  So \ln x gives $\ln x$ in contrast to ln x which gives $ln x$

Answer (score 4):

If you allow complex numbers (and use the principal branch of the logarithm), then the $\ln$ function does have attracting fixed points: approximately
$$ 0.3181315052 \pm 1.337235701 i$$

It appears that from most starting points in the positive reals, you end up approaching $0.3181315052 + 1.337235701 i$.

Comment: Thank you Robert! I was afraid everyone was so concerned with strictly positive domains that no one would mention the beauty of complex fixed points :D

Comment: Be careful about "any" starting point... note that if we ever get $0$ we have a problem! This means we have to exclude point $1,e,e^e...$ and so forth. Infinitely many examples where the points blow up to infinity, and then you have to define $\log(\infty)$

Comment: Good point.  I should change that "any"

Answer (score 2):

Eventually it will be undefined.  As you take logs of big numbers they go towards $1$.  When the number falls below $e$ (or whatever base you are using) the log will fall below $1$.  The next log will be negative.  The one after that fails.

Answer (score 2):

Observe the following:

$y = ln(ln(ln...))) \implies y = ln(y)$

does that equation have a solution?  No.